# Memory and adress of struct type in C Language?

Tags: c, memory-address

1.background

- **Althought I found the build-in types in C work similar to struct type, but i find something different.**
- **No knowledge of assembly language**

2.Test code

```c
// @compiler: gcc
// @machine: x64 Windows
#include <stdio.h>

struct IntNode {
    int integer;
    struct IntNode * next;
};

int main() {
    struct IntNode ints_list = {0, 0};
    printf("size of IntNode: %d\n", sizeof(struct IntNode));
    printf("Address of ints_list         : %p\n",  ints_list);         // 000000000061FE00
    printf("Address of &ints_list        : %p\n", &ints_list);         // 000000000061FE10
    printf("Address of &ints_list.integer: %p\n", &ints_list.integer); // 000000000061FE10
    printf("Address of &ints_list.next   : %p\n", &ints_list.next);    // 000000000061FE18
}
```

3.Picture

[image]

3.question

- **Why ints_list stand that memory**
- **whether ints_list is in variables table when app is compiled?**

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by passind data having wrong type to `printf`. Especially how to pass structures to functions will depend on the calling convension.

Comment: Also what does the "32bits" in the picture mean? You are in x64 environment, so a pointer `next` will have 64 bits.

Comment: `printf("Address of ints_list         : %p\n",  ints_list);` That's not an address of `ints_list`.

Comment: the "32bits" in the picture mean all 32bytes, I type the wrong word!But what the name of struct variable stands for~

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` and read the warnings. I am surprised that your code compiles at all. Basically, your question doesn't make sense, because the code is invalid. The expression `int_list` is not "The address of `int_list`". `int_list` is *the* `int_list` and `&int_list` would be "The address of `int_list`". Oh, and an additional comment: The expression "The adress of &int_list" (`&&int_list`) makes just as much sense as `&1`.

Comment: The memory layout of a structure is defined by your compiler. On most platforms the structure elements are aligned in memory depending on their size, so you might get padding (unused bytes) between the structure fields.

Comment: The `ints_list` variable is the value of the structure. Even though the behavior is undefined, it is a bit strange that it prints as the value you noted. I would have expected it to print as a 0-pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ints_list` is not the address of a structure, `&ints_list` is - your first `printf` invokes undefined behavior.

`structs` can be passed by value, and passing one to `printf` (that doesn't have the slightest idea how your structure should be printed) disguised as a pointer produces garbage output.